# How to check first letter of one string with last letter of another string inside of same char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

How can I complete the function canArrangeWords() ?

Question : Given a set of words check if we can arrange them in a list such that the last letter of any word and first letter of another word are same. The input function canArrangeWords shall contain an integer `num` and array of words `arr`. `num` denotes the number of word in the list `(1<=num<=100)`. `arr` shall contain words consisting of lower case letters between `'a' - 'z'` only . return 1 if words can be arranged in that fashion and -1 if cannot.

```
Input : 4  pot ten nice eye
output : 1
input : 3 fox owl pond 
output: -1
```

Please help me complete this program .
**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int canArrangewords(int,char [100][100]);


void main(){
    int n ,count=0 , i ; 
    char arrayS[100][100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%s",arrayS[i]);

    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",arrayS[i]);
        printf("\n");

    }
    printf("%c\n",arrayS[2][4]);

    canArrangewords(n , arrayS);

}

int canArrangewords(int n,char arrayS[100][100]){


    int i , j ;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = i+1 ; j < strlen(arrayS[j+1]); i++)
        {
            int flag = strlen(arrayS[j+1]) - 1;
            int temp = strcmp(arrayS[i][0],arrayS[j][flag]);



            }

        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all think of the way you can reach that answer.

If you only need to know if they can or can not be arranged and you do not have to do so your self you can use an empty array of int array[26] for each letter a-z.

The rule is that from all the first and last letters for all the words only two MAY appear an odd amount of times - the first letter of first word in list and the last letter in the last word in the list, the rest MUST appear an even amount of times. I would add a check to make sure the letters are lowercase as well. good luck!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MINASCII 97
#define LETTERS 26
void UpdateArray(char letter, int* arr)
{

  if(arr[letter - MINASCII] == 0)
  {
      ++arr[letter - MINASCII];
  }
  else
  {
     --arr[letter - MINASCII];/*for each second time same letter is seen reduce back to zero */
  }
}
int canArrangewords(int wordNum, char* wordArr[])
{
  int arr[LETTERS] = {0};
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0 ;
  char first;
  char last;
  char* string;
  for (i= 0; i< wordNum; ++i)
  {
     string = wordArr[i];
     first = string[0];
     last = string[strlen(string)-1];
     UpdateArray(first, &arr[0]);
     UpdateArray(last, &arr[0]);
 }

  for(i = 0; i< LETTERS; ++i)
  {
    count+=arr[i];
  }
  if(count == 2 || count == 0)/*either once each or twice -see word1 example in main*/
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}


int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  char* words[] = {"pot", "ten", "nice", "eye"};
  char* words1[] = {"pot", "ten", "nip"};
  char* words2[] = {"fox", "owl", "pond"};
  i = canArrangewords(4,words);
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = canArrangewords(3,words1);
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = canArrangewords(3,words2);
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Can you please explain this part of your code . I'm not able to understand clearly what this function is doing.                                      

  if(arr[letter - MINASCII] == 0)
  {
      ++arr[letter - MINASCII];   
  }
  else
  {
     --arr[letter - MINASCII];
  }

Comment: this function is set to tell us if a certain letter was seen an odd amount of times or not. for example- for the letter 'a'. the ascii val is 97 so we go to the array[in place[97-97] which is arr[0](for b it will be arr[98-97]==arr[1]). Now- for the first time we get a- the array will be updated to 1. if the letter appears again- an even amount of times we reset arr[0] to zero. if we get a 3 times arr[0] will be 1 and for 4 times will be zero again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your array of words into an array of pointers to words. Then you can simply exchange the pointers.

To speed things up, instead of a pointer to a word, have it point to a structure:

```
struct WORD {
    char *firstchar;   // begin of word
    char *lastchar;    // last char of word
} *words[100];         // array of 100 pointers to words
```

To read the words:

```
char buf[100];
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    scanf("%s",buf);
    int len= strlen(buf);
    words[i]= malloc(sizeof(struct WORDS));
    words[i]->firstchar= malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(words[i]->firstchar, buf);
    words[i]->lastchar= words[i]->firstchar + len-1;
}
```

Now compare and sort:

```
        if (*words[i]->lastchar == *words[j]->firstchar) {
            struct WORDS *tmp= words[i+1];
            words[i+1]= words[j];
            words[j]= tmp;
        }
```

Do this in a loop, a kind of bubble sort. I leave that to you.